# Unix and Oracle DB connectivity

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

Can someone share the complete setup for setting a shell script to connect to oracle DB, as my company doesn't give me complete access to few directories I am looking for an alternative option as well in which I just need list of minimum and maximum configurations (like is ora, listener access needed?) (is oracle directory access needed)? - any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Try this format. If you are running shell script from remote machine then you need to set the sqlplus utility and TNS path in remote machine.

```
#!/bin/bash

export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
UP='username/password'


RETVAL=`sqlplus -silent $UP <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
SELECT count(*) from table_name;
EXIT;
EOF`

echo $RETVAL
```